# can't change the Jenkins build queue after simple-queue-plugin installation

Tags: jenkins

I recently installed the Jenkins plugin simple-queue-plugin.
I can see the icon "Reset Simple-Queue". But no arrows to change the builds queue.
Note: I have "ADNINISTER" role
Any idea what I did I miss?

Comment: Please add step-by-step screenshots to explain the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin DOES mention this, but I'm not clear on what 'buildable' means in this context:

```
Orders buildable items only, for that reason blocked items do NOT have an arrow.
```